# Why this x64 shellcode doesn't work?(segmentation fault)

Tags: c, gdb, x86-64, shellcode, gcc

I found a simple shellcode on the internet.
Then, to test this shellcode, I make the simple ret overwrite code.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[100];

int main(void)
{
        char x=0;
        strcpy(buf, "\x31\xf6\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x56\x53\x54\x5f\x6a\x3b\x58\x31\xd2\x0f\x05");

        *(&x+9)=0x40;
        *(&x+10)=0x40;
        *(&x+11)=0x40;
        *(&x+12)=0x00;
        *(&x+13)=0x00;
        *(&x+14)=0x00;
        *(&x+15)=0x00;
        *(&x+16)=0x00;

        puts("end of program");
}
```

I compiled this using gcc like this.

```
gcc -o test test.c -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -no-pie -fno-pie -z execstack
```

and the following is the result of what I debugged with gdb.

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ gdb -q test                                                                                
Reading symbols from test...
(No debugging symbols found in test)
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401126 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000000000401127 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000040112a <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x000000000040112e <+8>:     mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x1],0x0
   0x0000000000401132 <+12>:    movabs rax,0x6e69622fbb48f631
   0x000000000040113c <+22>:    movabs rdx,0x5f54535668732f2f
   0x0000000000401146 <+32>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ef3],rax        # 0x404040 <buf>
   0x000000000040114d <+39>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ef4],rdx        # 0x404048 <buf+8>
   0x0000000000401154 <+46>:    movabs rax,0x50fd231583b6a
   0x000000000040115e <+56>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2eeb],rax        # 0x404050 <buf+16>
   0x0000000000401165 <+63>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x0000000000401169 <+67>:    add    rax,0x9
   0x000000000040116d <+71>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x40
   0x0000000000401170 <+74>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x0000000000401174 <+78>:    add    rax,0xa
   0x0000000000401178 <+82>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x40
   0x000000000040117b <+85>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x000000000040117f <+89>:    add    rax,0xb
   0x0000000000401183 <+93>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x40
   0x0000000000401186 <+96>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x000000000040118a <+100>:   add    rax,0xc
   0x000000000040118e <+104>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x0
   0x0000000000401191 <+107>:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x0000000000401195 <+111>:   add    rax,0xd
   0x0000000000401199 <+115>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x0
   0x000000000040119c <+118>:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x00000000004011a0 <+122>:   add    rax,0xe
   0x00000000004011a4 <+126>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x0
   0x00000000004011a7 <+129>:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x00000000004011ab <+133>:   add    rax,0xf
   0x00000000004011af <+137>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x0
   0x00000000004011b2 <+140>:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x00000000004011b6 <+144>:   add    rax,0x10
   0x00000000004011ba <+148>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x0
   0x00000000004011bd <+151>:   lea    rax,[rip+0xe40]        # 0x402004
   0x00000000004011c4 <+158>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x00000000004011c7 <+161>:   call   0x401030 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004011cc <+166>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004011d1 <+171>:   leave
   0x00000000004011d2 <+172>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *main+172
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4011d2
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/kali/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
end of program

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004011d2 in main ()
(gdb) si
0x0000000000404040 in buf ()
(gdb) x/30i $rip
=> 0x404040 <buf>:      xor    esi,esi
   0x404042 <buf+2>:    movabs rbx,0x68732f2f6e69622f
   0x40404c <buf+12>:   push   rsi
   0x40404d <buf+13>:   push   rbx
   0x40404e <buf+14>:   push   rsp
   0x40404f <buf+15>:   pop    rdi
   0x404050 <buf+16>:   push   0x3b
   0x404052 <buf+18>:   pop    rax
   0x404053 <buf+19>:   xor    edx,edx
   0x404055 <buf+21>:   syscall
   0x404057 <buf+23>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404059 <buf+25>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40405b <buf+27>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40405d <buf+29>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40405f <buf+31>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404061 <buf+33>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404063 <buf+35>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404065 <buf+37>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404067 <buf+39>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404069 <buf+41>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40406b <buf+43>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40406d <buf+45>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40406f <buf+47>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404071 <buf+49>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404073 <buf+51>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404075 <buf+53>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404077 <buf+55>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x404079 <buf+57>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40407b <buf+59>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x40407d <buf+61>:   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000404040 in buf ()
```

I think that 'xor esi,esi' don't generate segmentation fault, but It generated. Why the segmentation fault occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buf` variable is a global variable, which most likely is located inside `.data` section.

This section is not executable by default (it probably has RW permissions). You can check its permissions with `readelf` utility.

Since you are putting your shell code inside a buffer located in a non executable section of memory, upon executing first instructions, program segfaults.

Considering arguments you are passing to compile your code, I assume that you wanted your shell code to be located in the stack. Thus, to avoid segfault, your `buf` array should be a local variable (place your array inside `main` function).